# Handling of an undefined key in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary, error-handling

I'm trying to access some key / value pairs in a map, but don't always know which keys are available. I need to display an info message when certain keys are not found. This map is global and is used in a large number of places, e.i.

```
data = { 'KEY_A' : "A: {0}" }
```

My current implementation to catch the errors was to use a global error listener:

```
window.onerror = function(msg, url, line, col, error) {

    console.log("Error: " + msg + "\nURL: " + url + "\nLine: " + line);
    return false;
};
```

And then I am accessing the map with the following:

```
theKey = 'KEY_A';
console.log(data[theKey].format("extras"));
```

The issue here is that when the error handler fires, this is the message I see in my console:

```
Error: TypeError: data[theKey] is undefined
URL: http://localhost:8080/index.html#pages/errors
Line: 18
```

Issue being that the log contains the my variable name `theKey` instead of the actual value of the key itself, meaning that in the error handler I am not actually able to log the key that failed to be fetched?

How could I go about getting the value of the key inside of my error handler?

Comment: Yup, this is really annoying (I mean the engine probably does know what the current value is, there is nobreason to not pass it with the error). The only solution I can think of would be intercepting it with a Proxy, or doing proper checks on every access.

Comment: Does it have to be in error handler, or are you open to changing how you access the keys?

Comment: I was trying to go with the error handler approach as this would be a simple drop in fix, as opposed to being required to change line which accesses the map, which seems like it will be what I need to do.